# lead conversion trigger without account and contact

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

kindly help me with any example how to convert lead without any contact or account using setAccountId or setContactId.

Answer (score 2):

If a Lead is to be converted without a corresponding existing Contact or Account, then the Lead conversion will create a corresponding Account with name = `lead.company` and a corresponding Contact with email = `Lead.email` (and firstname/last name as well from Lead)

In addition, other fields are mapped by default to Account, Contact and Opportunity by the Lead Mapping rules. See `Setup | Lead | Fields | Lead Mapping`

You can add your own mapping of Lead custom fields

Comment: that knowledge was quite useful so just wanna ask if this piece of code is f9 or not........ Database.LeadConvert lcc = new Database.LeadConvert();                lcc.setAccountId(accMap.get(l.Company).Id);

Comment: [setContactId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_setContactId) and [setAccountId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_setAccountId) for documentation reference.

Comment: @vineet : `lcc.setAccountId(accMap.get(l.Company).Id); ` relies on case sensitive map keys; if no value found in map, then you'll get an attempt to de-reference null object on the `.id` expression.

Comment: do i have to delete contact or account somethng lyyk dat........after lead conversion

Comment: @vineet - edit your post with more code detail and your question(s) - let's not do this through comments

Comment: k..wil get back 2 u soon.

Comment: List<Lead> leadsToConvert = [Select Id, Company From Lead]; 
Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();
for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
    accNames.add(l.Company);
}                                                                                             Map<String,Account> accMap = new Map<String,Account>();
for(Account a : [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name = :accNames]){
    accMap.put(a.Name,a);
}

Comment: List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(l.Id);
 
    if(accMap.containsKey(l.Company)){
        lc.setAccountId(accMap.get(l.Company).Id);
    }
    
    leadConverts.add(lc);
} so wanna knw if the sample code is correct in order to hav no account on lead conversion.